# Validate jQuery plugin, field not required

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have got a problem with my form.

For the telephone field, I would like that is not required but in the right format if it's filled (10 digits).

If the form is empty and if it's validated, why the green image is displayed (validClass) ? How to make for that the image is displayed only if the field is completed and in the right format ?

Leave the form blank and confirm to see : http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/Y3GJr/

```
$('form').find('.error-message').hide();

$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'error-image',
    validClass: 'ok-image',
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorContainer: '#invalid-empty'
});

$("#form-general").validate({

    rules: {
        form_firstname: {
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 25,
            regex: /^[-a-zéèçàâA-Z)]+$/
        },
        form_name: {
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 25,
            regex: /^[-a-zéèçàâA-Z)]+$/
        },
        form_email: {
            email: true
        },
        form_telephone: {
            digits: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 10
        }
    },

        messages: {
        form_firstname: {
            required: "",
            minlength: "Please enter at least {0} characters",
            regex: "Please avoid spaces and special characters"
        },
        form_name: {
            required: "",
            minlength: "Please enter at least {0} characters",
            regex: "Please avoid spaces and special characters"
        },
        form_email: {
            required: "",
            email: "Your email address must be in the format name@domaine.com"
        },
        form_telephone: {
            required: false,
            minlength: "Please enter 10 digits",
            maxlength: "Please enter 10 digits",
            digits: "Please use only numbers"
        },
        form_message: ""
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('.btn-validate-group:visible').hide();
            $('.send-wait').fadeIn(300); 
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success : function() {
                        $('.send-wait').hide(); 
                        $('.send-success').fadeIn(300); 
                      },
                error : function(){
                        $('.send-wait').hide(); 
                        $('.send-error').fadeIn(300);  
                      }
        });
        return false;
        }

});

$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
    var re = new RegExp(regexp);
    return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
});
```

Comment: You said the telephone field is **not required**.  So if it's not required then it's going to be valid (green) if it's left blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the jQuery Validate plugin, a field will...

- pass the rules you've assigned so then it's "valid".  (gets the "valid" `class` and no messages)

OR

- fail at least one of the rules you've assigned so then it's "invalid".  (gets the "invalid" `class` and the error message)

**There is nothing between valid and invalid.**

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"For the telephone field, I would like that is not required but in the right format if it's filled (10 digits)."*

And this is exactly how your jsFiddle is already working.

In your case, the telephone field is not required, it's optional.  So when you leave it blank, it has passed validation... it's valid... it can not be anything else.

If it's not left blank, and filled out with letters or anything other than 10 characters, it fails your rules and it's marked as "invalid".

**Quote OP:**

> *"If the form is empty and if it's validated, why the green image is displayed (validClass) ?"*

See above.  A field can only be valid or invalid.  An "optional" field is considered "valid" whenever it's left blank.

---

**Side note:**  Instead of `digits` and `length` rules, you could use or modify one of the telephone rules that are already included as part of [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js).

---

Here is a very crude workaround that will bypass the `valid` class whenever the field is not required and left blank.  (This is not a typical behavior to avoid the "valid" class when the field is technically valid.)

I've assigned a `class` called `optional` to the telephone field and used the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions as follows...

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if ($(element).hasClass('optional') && $(element).val() == '') {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    }
},
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Y3GJr/3/**

**NOTE**:  This code is simplified in that it will not work properly if the form has `radio` elements.  For that case, refer back to the plugin's default callback functions and make the necessary additions.

Comment: Ouch, thank you. So if the field is not required we can write what we want ? (put letters instead of numbers). It's strange.

Comment: @Xroad, **no!... if the field is not required, it only means it can be left blank (this means "optional")**.  The other rules (`digits`, `length`) will not be ignored if/when it's filled out.  Just see your own jsFiddle... it will not allow letters.

Comment: ok so it's the behavior that I want. So we can't avoid the fact that the green image appears if the field stay blank ?

Comment: @Xroad, that's correct.  Your green image indicates "valid", and leaving it blank is indeed "valid".

Comment: ok so the customization of the plugin is limited. I thought it was an option for that.

Comment: @Xroad, the plugin is very customizable, but what you're asking doesn't make much sense.  If you want your blank field to be invalid, then make it required.  Otherwise, there is no "middle" state between "valid" and "invalid".

Comment: In fact this is just a story about a class (the green circle = validClass). I'm probably misspoke. A green circle appears in the "telephone" field while it stay blank. I would like that the green circle appears only if someone types numbers (the rule in the case where the field is filled) but I don't want that a green circle appears if the field stay blank, that's what does not make sense. Why a field stay blank is valid (green circle). This is not a story about "required" or not in fact lol

Comment: @Xroad, I understood you before, and my answer is still correct.  However, to avoid the application of the green circle means that the field cannot be marked "valid" whenever it's optional and blank (this is not typical since it's technically valid!).  A workaround involves changing how classes are assigned to valid fields.... or modifications to the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callbacks.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/Y3GJr/3/

Comment: Your code is just perfect ! Thank you a lot and sorry for my explanations. I learned basic english at school. So imagine for undestand the validate plugin documentation. I'm webdesigner, not developer, it's already hard to understand jquery then imagine in a language that is not my mother tongue. Whatever I would like to thank you for your help.

Comment: _"In fact this is just a story about a class"_ ~ True, but that's basically all this plugin does anyway... evaluate rules and assign classes.

Answer (score -3):

here is possible solution [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/229Xe/9/)
you have forgot the class of input

```
<input type="text" name="form_telephone" id="form_telephone" class="required requis-image"placeholder="Your phone number" />
```

I also slightly modified your jQuery code, look at the fiddle
I hope it can help you.

Comment: The OP specifically says, _"For the telephone field, I would like that is **not required**"_