# jquery validate - ignoring blank fields when submitting

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that allows a user to resend a username to the e-mail address listed.  It also has two input fields for new e-mail and new e-mail confirmation.  The idea is that if the address listed is bad, a new e-mail address can be entered and confirmed.  When the form is submitted, the e-mail is sent to the new address.  If both new address fields are left blank, then the e-mail goes to the address listed.  I have jquery.validate checking to make sure that email confirm === email, but if they're submitted blank I get my validated CSS showing because the blank email confirmation field matches the blank email field.

I have an onblur() "ignoreifblank" rule that covers tabbing through fields, but I need a real ignore if blank that covers the form submit as well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
preload(['https://url.to.images/tick-green.png']);

$('.ignoreifblank').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("success error");
        $(this).next('label').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).next('label').remove();
        $('#result').html('');
    }
});
$("#jqvForm").validate({
    ignore: ".ignore",
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: function (element) {
        if ($(element).hasClass('optional')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $(element).valid();
        }
    },
    highlight: function (label) {
        $(label).closest('.form-element').addClass('error')
            .closest('.form-element').removeClass('success');
        $('#result').html(''); 
    },
    success: function (label) {
        label.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.form-element').addClass('success');
    },
    rules: {
        new_email: {
            required: false,
            email: true,
            maxlength: 50
        },
        new_email_v: {
            equalTo: "#new_email"
        },
    },
    messages: {
        new_email: {
            email: "E-mail address does not appear to be valid.",
            maxlength: "Maximum length is 50 characters."
        },
        new_email_v: {
            equalTo: "E-mail addresses do not match."
        },
    }
});
```

The validation css and green tick only appear for a second when the form is submitted, but I'm thinking there's got to be a better way than that.  If I use the class="ignore" then it's just completed ignored.

Here be the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/stevelogan/W3gWn/

Comment: There does not appear to be any working validation in your jsFiddle, as I can submit the form no matter what I enter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate jQuery plugin, field not required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042321/validate-jquery-plugin-field-not-required)

Comment: I fixed the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/stevelogan/W3gWn/6/

Comment: Try the method/solution as per the link in previous comment.